# Polish space: C(X,Y) when?

Tags: functional-analysis

For which X,Y is the space of continuous functions $C(X,Y)$ from $X$ to $Y$ with the supremum norm a polish space and why?

Is it enough if $X$ is compact and $Y$ is Polish? why?

Comment: $Y$ should be itself Polish (because of constant functions). Compactness of $X$ is, at least when $X$ is metric, and necessary assumption in order to make the supremum norm well defined.

Comment: I changed the question from Y arbitrary to Polish